# iOS 10 error [access] <private> when using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller, ios10

I am using XCode 8 and testing with iOS 10.2 Beta.

I have added the Photos, PhotosUI and MobileCoreServices frameworks to project.

Very simple code:

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
#import <PhotosUI/PhotosUI.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, PHLivePhotoViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

@end
```

and implementation:

```
- (IBAction)grab:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;

    // make sure we include Live Photos (otherwise we'll only get UIImages)
    NSArray *mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, (NSString *)kUTTypeLivePhoto];
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;

    // bring up the picker
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As soon as I tap the button, the app crashes with very useless error:

`[access] <private>`

That's it. Nothing else.

Using break statements, the app seems to crash at "presentViewController".

This is a brand new app and I don't have anything else in the UI other than the grab button.

Also, testing on iOS 9.3, this works fine. Am I missing something which might be changed in iOS 10?

Comment: Clean and then build. If no change, could easily be a bug in Xcode 8 or the iOS 10 beta that will get resolved by Apple in a future update. I often find this is the case - if it's the last beta, or the GM release and it still isn't working, then would be the time to worry about fixing it.

Comment: yep, same issue even after clean and deleting the app :(

Comment: I wouldn't stress about it. It's a Beta release. Chances are more likely that it's an issue with the beta. I'd suggest developing on Xcode 7 until much closer to release.

Comment: ok makes sense! thank you @Jordan

Comment: @Jordan looks like there is a new requirement as of iOS 10. refer to solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38241350/1634905

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You may need to put the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in your plist.
Like

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos</string>
```

Check all the usage descriptions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).

Comment: sorry how did you find this release number?

Comment: In the iOS downloads website, I just solved with the correct UsageDescription key.

Comment: thank you, your answer resolved the issue right away! this is a new requirement since iOS 10. Welcome to Stack overflow btw!

Comment: Thanks so much!  I got burned by NSAppleMusicUsageDescription (accessing iTunes music library).

Comment: I used this in my app, and is still rejected 4 times now, I added this key in my project and also in my pods projects. and there is nowhere I could find the use of photos in my workspace. Any ideas why it's happening? one more is the message must be a reason?

Comment: @RaheelSadiq search in your workspace for photo, image or picker keywords. Maybe some pod is using some photo related class or library.

Comment: @iomer I already did that and searched other words as well like "asset" from ALAsset, I couldn't find any. I am using these libs: pod Alamofire, 
AlamofireImage, EGFloatingTextField, MXSegmentedPager. Any more hints or any idea that I can check, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @iomer i fixed the issue, I did add the key in info.plist, but I couldn't see it under Project > Target > Info. So I added there as well, and Apple passed my Binary. It happened to me once before as well with Facebook ID. Don't know why it wasn't shown there.

Comment: Or use the text "Big brother sees you"! ;)

Comment: I do this and it works well for photos, but my app still crashes when I try to capture video. Any ideas?

Comment: This should make your app not come through app store control.

Comment: What if you don't use photos? I got a warning that I needed the key, then when I added it with no value, it rejected the binary

Answer (score 132):

In iOS10, Before you access privacy-sensitive data like Camera, Contacts, and so on, you must ask for the authorization, or your app will crash when you access them.Then Xcode will log like:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSContactsUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

How to deal with this?

Open the file in your project named `info.plist`, right click it, opening as `Source Code`, paste this code below to it. Or you can open  `info.plist` as `Property List` by default, click the add button, Xcode will give you the suggest completions while typing `Privacy -`  with the help of keyboard  ⬆️ and ⬇️.

Remember to write your description why you ask for this authorization, between   `<string>` and `</string>`, or your app will be rejected by apple:

```
<!--  Photo Library -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use</string>

<!--  Camera -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>

<!--  Write To Image Gallery>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) save phots in gallry</string>


<!--  Microphone -->
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use</string>

<!--  Location -->
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>

<!--  Location When In Use -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>

<!--  Location Always -->
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) always uses location </string>

<!--  Calendars -->
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events</string>

<!-- ⏰ Reminders -->
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) reminder use</string>

<!--  Contacts -->
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use</string>

<!--  Motion -->
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use</string>

<!--  Health Update -->
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) heath update use</string>

<!--  Health Share -->
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) heath share use</string>

<!-- ᛒ Bluetooth Peripheral -->
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) Bluetooth Peripheral use</string>

<!--  Media Library -->
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) media library use</string>

<!--  Siri -->
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) siri use</string>

<!--  HomeKit -->
<key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) home kit use</string>

<!--  SpeechRecognition -->
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) speech use</string>

<!--  VideoSubscriber -->
<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) tvProvider use</string>
```

If it does not works, try to ask for the the background authorization:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <!-- something you should use in background -->
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Or go to `target -> Capabilities -> Background Modes -> open the background Modes`:

[image]

then clean your Project, run it.

Go to here for more information:  [**iOS10AdaptationTips**](https://github.com/ChenYilong/iOS10AdaptationTips/) .

Comment: I used photos nowhere, and apple is rejecting my app, any idea?. I check all the pods projects as well

Comment: @RaheelSadiq Remember to write your description why you ask for this authorization, between   `<string> ` and `</string>`, or your app will be rejected by apple.

Answer (score 23):

in iOS 10 you need to add the key mentioned in below image if you are using camera or photo gallery in your app

[image: .plist image]

Answer (score 14):

You need the add the new privacy settings to you info.plist.

*Don't forget to add the value describing why the app need to access the service.*

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In iOS 10, Apple has changed how you can access any user private data types.

You need to add the **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description** key to your app’s `Info.plist` and their usage information.

For more information please find the below GIF.

[image: GIF]

Or if you want to add via `info.plist` then you need to add **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** key.

Just copy and paste below string in `info.plist`.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Take the photo</string>
```

Please find the below GIF for more information.

[image: GIF]

Comment: and also 
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key><string>Take the photo</string>