# UIImagePickerController crashes on iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

On presenting `UIImagePickerController` with photo library source on *iOS10*, my app crashes.

On *iOS10 with* camera source and on *iOS9* with photo library and camera sources, the app does not crash.

The app is written in *Swift 2.2* and built by *Xcode 7.3.1*.

Why does the crash occur?

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: stack trace]

Comment: must have added key in plist for  permission `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236723/ios-10-error-access-private-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: I already added the keys. But my app crashes.

Comment: From your log, I can see you are using UIImagePickerController and it is using PHPhotolobrary. But these two libraries has undergone some changes in the iOS 10.0. Please find the changes in the link here. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Swift/UIKit.html

Comment: It would help us if you could give the code to help you better.

Comment: I added code as postscript.

Comment: This code crashed similarly. 'let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)'

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236723/ios-10-error-access-private-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller/38650785#38650785

Comment: same issue, privacy keys added but still crash on dismis uiimagepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the crash by updating to the latest Xcode version.
The problem has been discussed here as well: https://github.com/Leanplum/Leanplum-iOS-SDK/issues/12

Comment: Yeah,sometimes the 3part may not suit iOS10

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. If you just delete Leanplum.trackAllAppScreens() this line it works,either but probably you will not receive in-app notifications.

Comment: We tested with Swift 3 and Xcode 8 and we couldn't reproduce your issue. It seems its not related to Leanplum SDK and using the latest Xcode version resolves the issue. Please let us know otherwise ;)

Answer (score 51):

You may need to put the NSCameraUsageDescription (if your app uses the Camera) and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription (if your app uses the Photo Library) in your plist. Like below,

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your camera</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your photo library</string>
```

Answer (score 29):

Rahul's answer is perfect. If you prefer to add it straight into your plist rather than via the plist's source code then just do the following.
[image: plist additions]

Answer (score 1):

permission keys in plist for permission For Camera (also need Microphone permission) and PhotoLibrary

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
```

${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
```

${PRODUCT_NAME} Microphone Usage

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
```

${PRODUCT_NAME} PhotoLibrary Usage