# Abort with payload error in implementing image picker in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I started learning the iOS development using swift and Xcode today. I am absolute beginner to iOS development. Now I am trying to open an image picker. But when I fire the event to open image picker interacting with UI, it is giving me the following error:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1081980a0 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x1081980a5 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x1081980a8 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1081980aa <+10>: jae    0x1081980b4               ; <+20>
    0x1081980ac <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1081980af <+15>: jmp    0x108191caf               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1081980b4 <+20>: retq   
    0x1081980b5 <+21>: nop    
    0x1081980b6 <+22>: nop    
    0x1081980b7 <+23>: nop
```

I exactly followed the tutorial. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameTextField.delegate = self;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text;

    }

    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        let imagePickerController  = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            photoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            photoImageView.image = pickedImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

The error is thrown when I click on the image view to open the image picker. Why is that error thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController crashes on iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611490/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-on-ios10)

Comment: So updating xcode is the only solution?

Comment: I think that the solution is add permission keys in .plist.

Comment: Oh yeah. Got it. Thanks. It worked. Thanks so much.