# IOS 10 UIImagePickerController Delegate Not Being Called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have setup the following to select an image whilst using an IPad. The problem is that the delegate never seems to get called. I've placed breakpoints in but they are never activated.

**.H**

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

**.M**

```
- (IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender {

self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

// This method is called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera.
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

//You can retrieve the actual UIImage
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
//Or you can get the image url from AssetsLibrary
NSURL *path = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Thanks

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236723/ios-10-error-access-private-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: I did copy and paste your code as you wrote in the new sample project I created, but it works. one thing that I did add without your description was info.plist Privacy Photo library usage.

Comment: Hi, checked the info.plist and the privacy setting is already there. Really strange because I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: its work fine for me also

Comment: Is everyone using an IPad?

Comment: Do not retain image picker controller in a property. Do not present as UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.

Comment: Ok restarted the IPad and also removed the app and reinstalled and all seems to be working ok now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you used Xcode8 to run the project, please check the project's info.plist, make sure there is a key for "Privacy Photo library usage".

your code is right, maybe the problem is the info.plist.

Comment: Hi that was already there, turned out to be a bug because after restarting the Ipad it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that the picker was being garbage collected as soon as the image was picked, so the delegate wasn't called.

I needed to ensure that a strong reference to the picker was made before presenting it.

Once that was done, it worked fine.