# UIPikerViewController for ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller, uipickerviewdelegate

I wrote code about a year ago, where I load photo or picture to network. But now this code not working. I think it is connected to that now I use IOS 10.

In logs :

> [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
>
> Reporter[34067:1053969] Response {
>       code = 5;
>       msg = "File was empty"; }

Please, help me, what's wrong?

Info.plist
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFJSy.png)

AddComplaintController.h

```
@interface AddComplaintController : UIViewController  <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UITextViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *photoButton;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photo;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *photoUrl;
...different properties...
@end
```

AddComplaintController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 UIButton *photoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 11, 28, 26)];
    [photoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [photoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (IBAction)addPhoto:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [actionSheet bk_addButtonWithTitle:@"Все фотографии" handler:^{

        [self selectPhoto];
    }];
    [actionSheet bk_addButtonWithTitle:@"Камера" handler:^{
        [self takePhoto];
    }];

    [actionSheet bk_setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Отмена" handler:^{
        [self.text becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (IBAction)takePhoto {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device has no camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];
        [self.text becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

}
- (IBAction)selectPhoto {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [dataManager.arrOfTags replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Фото"];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    NetManager *netManager = [NetManager new];

    [netManager uploadPhoto:info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] andCallbackBlock:^(NSString *imageURL, double progress){


        if (progress <= 1.0 && progress > 0) {

            hud.progress = progress;

        }

        else if (progress == 0.0) {

            self.photoUrl = imageURL;
            [hud hide:YES];
            NSLog(@"photo url %@", self.photoUrl);
            if (self.photoUrl && !self.photoIsSticked) {

                UIImageView *stick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 8, 14, 14)];
                stick.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"];
                [keyboardToolbar addSubview:stick];
                self.photoIsSticked = YES;
            }


        }

    }];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self.text becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

NetManager.m

```
- (void)uploadPhoto: (UIImage *) photo andCallbackBlock:(void (^)(NSString*, double))photoURL {

    NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@api/v1/upload?token=%@", kBaseURLPath, token];

    NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.5f);

    NSDictionary *parms = @{@"command": @"upload",
                            @"title":@"foto"};


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:urlString parameters:parms constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataImage name:@"file" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Response %@", responseObject);

        photoURL(responseObject[@"value"], 0.0);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        photoURL (nil, (double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: What is not working pinking photo from picker view or upload photo not working ??

Comment: @CodeChanger not pinking photo from picker view.

Comment: @МарияТимофеева Have you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236723/ios-10-error-access-private-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Have you debug your code where actually you got this log ? in uploadPhoto method ?

Comment: @NiravD yes, i checked this, but our problems are not equals.

Comment: @CodeChanger I had error [Generic]  when I open preview photo. After choosen the photo  upload method will start. After all i have logs where written  "file was empty".

Comment: You need to key for privacy as below link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39680377/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks look more attentively, I already use these settings.

Comment: yes ,you need to also add value with $(PRODUCT_NAME) .

Comment: @KKRocks I try , it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code & comments i assume that Image object will be released while you are uploading your image.

Try below code :

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [dataManager.arrOfTags replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Фото"];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    NetManager *netManager = [NetManager new];

    UIImage *imgPhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [netManager uploadPhoto:imgPhoto andCallbackBlock:^(NSString *imageURL, double progress){

        if (progress <= 1.0 && progress > 0) {
            hud.progress = progress;
        }

        else if (progress == 0.0) {

            self.photoUrl = imageURL;
            [hud hide:YES];
            NSLog(@"photo url %@", self.photoUrl);
            if (self.photoUrl && !self.photoIsSticked) {

                UIImageView *stick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 8, 14, 14)];
                stick.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick"];
                [keyboardToolbar addSubview:stick];
                self.photoIsSticked = YES;
            }
        }
    }];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self.text becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Try to create new object of UIImage and pass it into your Upload method.

Hope this will help you.