# creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I've tried all the solutions online so far and none seem to work. Here is my class (the view controller  is initialized correctly.) My code doesn't seem to reach the `imagePickerController` method, and throws the error mentioned in the title of this question. Any ideas?

```
class ImageCell : UICollectionViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!


    var ic:ImageController?


    func singleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        self.selectImageFromPhotoLibrary()
    }


    func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary()
    {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = ic
        ic?.present(imagePickerController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {

        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        myImage.image = selectedImage
        ic?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        ic?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added privacy access for library in in info.plist, if not check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236723/ios-10-error-access-private-when-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Have you included UINavigationController delegate?

Comment: You have not initialise ic, you just declare it. When you use ic, it will always return nil. So Jut initialise ic as like 'ic: ImageController = ImageController()' and then use.

Comment: I declare ic when I create cells in the view controller, so I don't think thats the solution. When I debug ic is declared.

Comment: I added the UINavigationController delegate, but got the same error.

Comment: have you did what nirav asked you?

Comment: Yeah, had that in already.

Comment: Are you sure it's a true error? Since Xcode 8, my normal process is to add **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disabled** to my schemes. Last week I needed to enable this and began seeing the exact same console note. Yet - everything works as it has for almost a year! No build errors, no issues within the app, and AFAIK, Apple has no problems with the app. I know the sounds odd, but try adding that to your scheme.